# Manipulate all url inside a string and return new string modified in python

Tags: python

I need a function that recognize all urls inside it and get it for manipulate, then recreate original string with urls modified.

tried:

```
old_msg = 'This is an url https://ebay.to/3bxNNfj e this another one https://amzn.to/2QBsX7t'

def manipulate_url(url):
    #example of manipulation, in real i get query replacement tags and other complex....
    if 'ebay' in url:
        new_url = url + "/another/path/"
    if 'amzn' in url:
        new_url = url + "/lalala/path/"
    return new_url

result = re.sub('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', manipulate_url, old_msg)
print(result)

#expected result based on my exmple:
#This is an url https://ebay.to/3bxNNfj/another/path/ e this another one https://amzn.to/2QBsX7t/lalala/path/
```

but i get :
    TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, re.Match found

Comment: Trying to run this code on a fresh Python 3 interpreter gives `TypeError: argument of type '_sre.SRE_Match' is not iterable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the docs for [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) says, the function you supply will receive a [`match object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects).

to get the URL (the full match), use [`.group(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) on it, like this:

```py
import re

old_msg = 'This is an url https://ebay.to/3bxNNfj e this another one https://amzn.to/2QBsX7t'

def manipulate_url(match):
    url = match.group(0)
    #example of manipulation, in real i get query replacement tags and other complex....
    if 'ebay' in url:
        new_url = url + "/another/path/"
    if 'amzn' in url:
        new_url = url + "/lalala/path/"
    return new_url

result = re.sub('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', manipulate_url, old_msg)
print(result)
```

Output:

> This is an url https://ebay.to/3bxNNfj/another/path/ e this another one https://amzn.to/2QBsX7t/lalala/path/

Comment: thank you for explanation! it works as expected. btw....my pattern to recognize url work but...it there someelse better or i can use this? thanks a lot

Comment: Looks like the standard URL regex to me, I don't know any better way